# How do I count iterations in a Chapel forall loop

Tags: chapel, forall

I'd like to know how many times a loop is executed when using Chapel's `forall`.  This code using the [CDO Library](https://github.com/marcoscleison/cdo) fails, and I'm sure it's right to do so.  Could someone give me a good example?

```
var j:int = 0;
writeln("\n=== FORALL LOOP ===");
forall row in cursor {
  writeln("from: ", row['from_nm'], "\tto: ", row['to_nm']);
  j += 1;
}
writeln("Expected 10 rows, got ", j);
```

The error is

```
faerr.chpl:59: error: illegal lvalue in assignment
faerr.chpl:57: note: The shadow variable 'j' is constant due to forall intents in this loop
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, most variable types (except arrays) are copied in to a `forall` loop so you can't modify them. This is done to avoid race conditions in the common case. If you want to be able to modify `j` within the `forall` loop, you need to use a `forall intent`.

Forall intents are defined in the "Data Parallelism" section of the [Chapel language spec](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/latest/_downloads/chapelLanguageSpec.pdf).  Since this code wants to reduce the `j` values of the tasks to a single value, you can use a [reduce intent](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/latest/technotes/reduceIntents.html) on the `forall` loop to count the iterations:

```
var j:int = 0;
writeln("\n=== FORALL LOOP ===");

forall row in cursor with (+ reduce j) {
  writeln("from: ", row['from_nm'], "\tto: ", row['to_nm']);
  j += 1;
}

writeln("Expected 10 rows, got ", j);
```